# how to find whether any of the comma separated values exists in the column

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i want to find whether that whether any of the values 1,2,3,4,5 exists in a column of the tables which has record 4,5,7,8,6

i am using find in sets but it is not providing the right results

```
$query = $this->db->select('id AS grp_id')
                   ->where("FIND_IN_SET('1,2,3,4,5',u_ids)!=", 0)
                   ->get('tb_grp');
$data = $query->result_array();
```

in the above query i want to find whether any of the values 1,2,3,4,5 exists in any row of the column u_ids

Comment: You should normalise your data.

Comment: Try not to violate the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and define this in a proper, relational structure.

Comment: Everything about this is simply depressing. Be happy, and normalise your schema

Answer (score -1):

It's not fully clear, but I've inferred from your question that:

- You have a table called `tb_grp`, with fields `id` and `u_id`
- The `u_id` field contains a comma-separated list of IDs

For example:

```
+----+---------+
| id |   u_id  |
+----+---------+
| 1  | 4,5,6,7 |
| 2  | 1,8,5,9 |
| 3  | 3,4,7,8 |
+----+---------+
```

- Based on this, you want to run a query that will return any rows where `u_id` contains one of the following 'ids':  `1,2,3,4 or 5`

In MySQL, running the following query:

```
SELECT id AS grp_id from tb_grp
WHERE CONCAT(u_ids,",") REGEXP "(1,|2,|5,|9,)";
```

Would return:

```
+--------+
| grp_id |
+--------+
|   1    |
|   2    |
+--------+
```

Now, I haven't been near codeigniter for a few years, but I expect the following should work:

```
$where = "CONCAT(u_ids,',') REGEXP '(1,|2,|3,|4,|5,)';
$query = $this->db->select('id AS grp_id')
                   ->where($where)
                   ->get('tb_grp');
$data = $query->result_array();
```

**An attempt to explain this**

You have a string that contains numbers that are followed by a comma in all but (probably) the last item in the list.  We're going to RegEx search the list, but searching for "2," wouldn't get a match if the last in the list was a '2' (as it has no following comma).  If we searched for "2" without a comma, then we'd get a match on '12', '20' and so on.  Therefore, the best way to make this robust is to concat a comma to the end of your list, then search for either "1," or "2," or "3," and so on.

I hope that helps, or at least gets your near what you're looking to acheive

Comment: how you are making (1,|2,|5,|9,) out of 1,2,3,5,6 as when i put this as query SELECT *
FROM `tb_event`
WHERE CONCAT(grp_ids,',') REGEXP (3,4)
its giving error like
Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: (1,|2,|5,|9,) was an example based on some random data (hence why I said **for example**).   As for the rest of your comment, you've not followed what I explained - you've 'broken' the query again.   The error you're seeing is the result of misusing the `REGEXP` function - it would need to be `REGEXP '(3,|4,)'`  i.e. look for "3," or "4,"